# error: ‘struct task_struct’ has no member named ‘it_virt_value’

Tags: linux, kernel

I am trying to create a system call in Linux ubuntu-studio that has the following functionality:

bring virtual memory the larger process and how much bytes it occupies.

below is the implementation code of the system call:

```
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/printk.h>
#include <linux/sched.h>

struct pid_size{
    int pid;
    unsigned long size;
};


struct pid_size pid maiorMemoriaVirtual(void)
{
    struct task_struct *task;
    struct task_struct *maior = NULL;

    for_each_process(task)
    {
        if(maior == NULL)
            maior = task; 
        else if(task->it_virt_value > maior->it_virt_value)
            maior = task;
    }

    struct pid_size retorno;
    retorno.pid = maior->pid;
    retorno.size = maior->it_virt_value;

    return retorno;
}
```

When compiling to try compiling the kernel got the following error:

```
kernel/maiorMemoriaVirtual.c: In function ‘sys_maiorMemoriaVirtual’:
kernel/maiorMemoriaVirtual.c:19:21: error: ‘struct task_struct’ has no member named ‘it_virt_value’
         else if(task->it_virt_value > maior->it_virt_value)
                     ^
kernel/maiorMemoriaVirtual.c:19:44: error: ‘struct task_struct’ has no member named ‘it_virt_value’
         else if(task->it_virt_value > maior->it_virt_value)
                                            ^
kernel/maiorMemoriaVirtual.c:23:5: warning: ISO C90 forbids mixed declarations and code [-Wdeclaration-after-statement]
     struct pid_size retorno;
     ^
kernel/maiorMemoriaVirtual.c:25:25: error: ‘struct task_struct’ has no member named ‘it_virt_value’
     retorno.size = maior->it_virt_value;
                         ^
make[1]: ** [kernel/maiorMemoriaVirtual.o] Erro 1
```

Answer (score 1):

I came across a similar problem while working on an assignment and I have realized that there are quite a few changes that have been made to the definition of the 'task_struct' structure.

My guess is that you are looking for accumulated virtual memory usage. You might find this link useful. [Accumulated Virtual Memory usage](http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v2.6.36/include/linux/sched.h#L1410)

[Link to the task_struct definition in kernel 2.6.36](http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v2.6.36/include/linux/sched.h#L1163http://)